# Why do people get addicted to things like TV, Facebook, games?

Tags: addiction

I am studying for exams but there's a TV series I couldn't get enough of.

Is there any explanation to all addiction thing that happens with our brain?

**EDIT**
I'm not talking about procrastination but generalized addiction about non chemical(drugs) things that happens with us.

Comment: Hi @McGucket.  Welcome at CogSci! Could you perhaps provide a little more information?  For example, are you looking for theories on procrastination or are you looking for reasons for TV shows drawing attention?

Comment: I agree with @Chris. The questions about why people get absorbed with TV shows is different to why people procrastinate studying. You need to clarify which question you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! May I also suggest a narrowing of the stated question (from your note, it sounds like you are not interested in the explanation for all addition, but primarily addictions that are not drug based).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least two phenomenons can be found here :

1. The drive to wath the TV series is higher than the drive to study.
2. The TV series are structured in such a way to attract and hook viewers.

I will try to answer the second :

TV series i.e. [soap operas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_opera), [Lost TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(TV_series)) etc mostly use two components to create addiction to viewers : curiosity and emotionally charged stories.

> [**Curiosity-drive theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity#Curiosity-drive_theory) relates to the undesirable experiences of
>   "uncertainty". The reduction of these unpleasant feelings, in turn, is
>   **rewarding**. This theory suggests that people desire coherence and understanding in their thought processes. When this coherence is
>   disrupted by something that is unfamiliar, uncertain, or ambiguous, it
>   is curiosity-drive theory that attempts to gather information and
>   knowledge of the unfamiliar to restore coherent thought processes once
>   again.

...

> British psychologist Edward B. Titchener (1867–1927) might have argued
>   that we become glued to complex, **[emotionally-charged stories](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-babble/201403/why-were-wired-binge-watch-tv)** because
>   of our ability to recognize the feelings of others. A newly identified
>   phenomenon at the time, Titchener coined the term empathy in 1909. In
>   addition to identifying others' discomfort or elation, "cognitive
>   empathy" examines how humans can also adopt others' psychological
>   perspectives, including those of fictional characters.